# How to sort in ractive.js

Tags: sorting, ractivejs

I have got the following data (sample):

```
"data": {
    "eventsHeading": "Upcoming events",
    "eventsToBeDisplayed": 3,
    "allEventLinkText": "See all events",
    "eventsList": [
{
    "eventDate": "23/10/2016",
    "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 1"
},
{
    "eventDate": "22/10/2016",
    "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 2"
},
{
    "eventDate": "24/10/2016",
    "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 3"
},
{
    "eventDate": "21/10/2016",
    "eventTitle": "EVENT INFO 4"
}
    ]
}
```

And I have something like this:

```
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {{#eventsList:i}}
                {{#i < eventsToBeDisplayed}}
                    <tr>
                                <td class="date-column">{{eventDate}}</td>
                                <td class="text-link truncate-text"><ux-anchor class="text-link" href="{{link}}">{{eventTitle}}</ux-anchor>
                    </tr>
                {{/}}
                {{/}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

So currently, this will loop to fetch only 3 Data and it will show:

```
23/10/2016   EVENT INFO 1

22/10/2016   EVENT INFO 2

24/10/2016   EVENT INFO 3
```

What i want to do is sort first the eventDate so i will fetch the incoming eventDate, so it will be like this:

```
21/10/2016   EVENT INFO 4

22/10/2016   EVENT INFO 2

23/10/2016   EVENT INFO 1
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sort the data in some lifecycle event (or perhaps on observed changes / custom events?) in your ractive instance. Since you have your dates as date strings, you need to parse them into a date object before you can compare them.

```
this.set("eventsList",this.get("eventsList").sort( function (a, b) {
    var aParts = a.eventDate.split("/");
    var bParts = b.eventDate.split("/");
    return new Date(aParts[2],aParts[1],aParts[0]) < new Date(bParts[2],bParts[1],bParts[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pq7yrncv/

Comment: Ok, i created a seperate *.js file for this event. So *.json file should only have the data. Thanks a lot for this @Leakim